# Receiving In-sufficient privileges error upon updating case owner only for a particular STATUS value

Tags: insufficient-privileges

I am facing a weird issue. When my 'Case' is in **"NEW"** status and I am trying to change the owner of the case, I am receiving the insufficient privilege error. But with all the other **'STATUS'** values I am able to modify the case owner. I am working with the 'System Admin' profile. What might be the cause of the same ?

Thanks!
Ruchi

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the issue. It was due to a workflow rule and a trigger on case object. When I was trying to update the owner when the status was new. And the workflow rule was trying to change the status to 'Assigned' . But due to a condition present in my trigger the workflow was unable to update the status which was why I was receiving insufficient privileges error.